# Calculate coefficient to get normal speed animation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I use some WPF animation to move UserControl within vertically.

Here is the code

```
public void RestartAnimation(double contentControlHeight, double thisHeight)
        {
            if (cp != null && IsLoaded)
                da.From = contentControlHeight;  
                da.To = -thisHeight;
                da.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
                da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.Duration)); 
                sb.Children.Clear();
                sb.Children.Add(da);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));
                Storyboard.SetTarget(da, cp);
                sb.Begin();           
            }
        }
```

**It works fine but I have discovered if the height is greater then the motion is faster.**

So I need to realize 2 things:

Some speed range values ie 1-100 (very slow - super fast) and internally I need some **formula/coefficient** to do it.

I did some experiments with the static speed and *different height* and got some table.

[image]

Please help me to figure out **which calculation I have to do to just set the speed range (1-100) and it should work fine regardless** `StackPanel` **height**.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you should be interested in the ratio (StackPanel Height / ContentControl Height), but rather simply the *difference* (StackPanel Height - ContentControl Height).

Say that you want your speed to be 30 pixels per second (actually rather slow, but just going from your "speed" value above). You would be interested in setting your duration based on how many seconds it will take to cover the pixel distance (the difference in heights) at a rate of 30 pixels per second.

So you would just need:

```
var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((thisHeight - contentControlHeight) / pixelPerSecondSpeed);
```

This is how you would leave speed at a constant.

Answer (score 2):

You need to normalize the duration of the animation. So let's say that for a ratio of stack panel height to content control height of `0.5`, a duration of `N` seconds is considered "normal speed" (you should decide what `N` is at this point).

So now let's say there is some ratio `R` different than `0.5` and we want to find out what the animation duration should be. That's easy:

```
var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(N * R / 0.5);
```

Let's suppose that you want to work with a normalized duration scale too. Let's say on this linear scale 100 corresponds to "normal" speed; let's say that lower numbers make for a *faster* animation, so 1 is "almost instant" and 200 is "half the speed of normal". Let's call the normalized duration `norm`. You 'd then have:

```
var absoluteDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(N * R / 0.5);
var normalizedDuration = absoluteDuration.Seconds * norm / 100;
```