# JS/CSS Animation Speed Relative to Object Size

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have a JS function which animates the `height` of a `div` at a speed of `0.5 seconds`. This `height` value is **dynamically defined** upon content load, and it can be anywhere from `200px` to `6000px` or more.

The problem I'm having is that when the `height` is larger than `800px` my default speed value of `0.5 seconds` makes the animation happen way too fast. And if I increase the default speed value to, say `2 seconds`, the animation gets too slow when the div is under `800px` tall.

How can I make the animation speed relative to the div height so the animation feels the same regardless of the height value?

I've tried this: [Calculate coefficient to get normal speed animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600775/calculate-coefficient-to-get-normal-speed-animation)
. But I get the following error:
`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TimeSpan`

I'd appreciate it if anyone has any ideas - Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have directly used the answer to that questions, then the `TimeSpan` object will not exist in your code unless you have created it, it isn't a jQuery or JavaScript native function but a Microsoft .NET function.

You could implement something similar in JS like so:

```
var duration = (thisHeight - contentControlHeight) / pixelPerSecondSpeed;
```

If you use the value from the table in the question you referenced, ie:

```
var contentControlHeight = 500;
var pixelPerSecondSpeed = 30;
var thisHeight = parseInt($('#someDiv').height());

// This should return the correct animation duration
var duration = (thisHeight - contentControlHeight) / pixelPerSecondSpeed;
```

I couldn't test this, a jsFiddle or some more example code would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much Sinan - This works great. Also thank you for explaining what the other post liked to in my original message is about. I had my suspicions it was't a JS-specific approach but It was the closest related answer I could find. Cheers.

Comment: @unwork No worries, glad to be of help. Could you mark the answer as correct please.

Comment: I've actually rushed into this Sinan: It's not working properly, the animation is too fast on shorter distances and too slow on longer ones. I'll create an example in Codepen when I have some time later today.

Comment: Okay i'll keep an eye out